# How to make while loop to keep track of tries?

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

> Write a program using the switch statement name GradeReport that reads
>   a grade from the user and prints the comments accordingly.
>
> Instruction: Prompt the user to enter their grade user must be prompt
>   to enter a numeric grade (0 to 100) if the input isn't an integer
>   between 0 and 100, prompt the user to re-enter
>
> Use a do loop for the re-enter of grade then if condition is not met
>   or grade is not between 0 and 100 then prompt the user on the screen
>   as follows ("Error: You must enter an integer between 0 and 100");”
>
> Also incorporate a while loop to keep track of tries. create a
>   variable name “tries” that will keep track of tries no more than 3
>   therefore if the input isn't an integer between 0 and 100, prompt the
>   user to reenter

I have a problem figuring out while loop to keep track of tries.

Here's what I have:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeReport {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int grade, category;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  do {
   System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
   grade = scan.nextInt();
   if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
    break;
   System.out.println("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");
  } while (true);

  int tries = 1;
  while (tries <= 3) {
   System.out.println("Tries: " + tries);
   tries++;

   category = grade / 10;

   System.out.print("That grade is ");
   switch (category) {
    case 10:
     System.out.println("a perfect score. Well done.");
     break;
    case 9:
     System.out.println("well above average. Excellent.");
     break;
    case 8:
     System.out.println("above average. Nice job.");
     break;
    case 7:
     System.out.println("average.");
     break;
    case 6:
     System.out.println("below average. You should see the");
     System.out.println("instructor to clarify the material " + "presented in class.");
     break;
    default:
     System.out.println("not passing.");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: "_I have a problem figuring out while loop to keep track of tries_" Could you explain / describe a bit more what your specific problem is ? What have you tried, and what are you getting stuck with ?

Comment: I want to make a variable "tries" that will keep track of tries no more than 3 therefore if the input isn't an integer between 0 and 100, prompt the user to reenter. I have an idea of how to do it but not exactly.

Comment: downvoting this, is in my opinion wrong. it is a clear consise question, and it should not be downvoted just because this might be a very simple solution for most of us. Remember that we were all new at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part where you try:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
    grade=scan.nextInt();
    if(grade>=0 && grade<=100)
    break;
    System.out.println ("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");   
    }while(true);
```

This is the part where you think you count the tries:

```
    int tries = 1;
    while (tries <= 3) {
         System.out.println("Tries: " + tries);
         tries++;
         ...

You need to define `int tries = 0;` before trying, and integrate the incrementation inside the loop where you actually try. I'm sure you can figure out the rest yourself. You seem to be pretty close :)
```

**EDIT:** Due to others trying to give you the complete answer (and not too well), here is how I would do it:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class GradeReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int grade, category;

        int tries = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            tries++;
            System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
            grade = scan.nextInt();
            if(grade >= 0 && grade <= 100){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("attempt " + tries + " unsuccessful");
            if(tries >= 3){
                System.out.println("No more attempts.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");

        } while (true);

        if(grade >= 0 && grade <= 100){

            category = grade / 10;

            System.out.print("That grade is ");
            switch (category) {
            case 10:
                System.out.println("a perfect score. Well done.");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("well above average. Excellent.");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("above average. Nice job.");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("average.");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("below average. You should see the");
                System.out.println("instructor to clarify the material " + "presented in class.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("not passing.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this: int tries = 1;
while (tries <= 3) {
     System.out.println("Tries: " + tries);
     tries++;

Comment: Could you show what the rest of it looks like for it too keep track of tries?

Comment: What do you mean by "define int tries = 0; before trying, and integrate the incrementation inside the loop where you actually try." what would the rest of it looks like? @KjetilNordin

Comment: You need to define int tries before you start trying, right? Then you need to count every try you do. You can decide to count only when tries fail, and do it after every try, but the most logical thing in my mind, would be to say "starting try nr 1", "starting try nr 2" etc. that way, you would increment tries, before actually trying, and counting tries, instead of counting failed tries. You can of course decide for yourself if you want to have a 1-index or 0-index based counter, but know that you would then have to increment outside the exit clause. With the 0-index, you don't need a break.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to set the `tries` variable before looping for input:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int tries = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
        grade=scan.nextInt();
        if(grade>=0 && grade<=100)
            break;
        tries += 1;
        System.out.println ("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");   
        }while(tries < 3);

    System.out.println("Tries: " + (tries + 1));
```

Comment: why change the index of tries to 0, if you are going to increment it after the break? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KjetilNordin: Just because as an old programmer I am used to count from 0... And please notice I use it later as `tries + 1` for a human comprehensible value.

Comment: I would start from 0 as well, but I would definitely increment the index in the beginning of the loop instead of the end :) @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
int grade, category;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tries = 0;
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
        grade = scanner.nextInt();
        if(grade<0 || grade>100){
            System.out.println ("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");
        } else {
            break;
        }
        tries++;
    } while (tries < 3);
    System.out.print(grade);
```

in place where you have following code

```
int grade, category;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0 to 100): ");
            grade=scan.nextInt();
            if(grade>=0 && grade<=100)
                break;
            System.out.println ("Error: You must re-enter an integer between 0 and 100");   
            }while(true);

        int tries = 1;
        while (tries <= 3) {
            System.out.println("Tries: " + tries);
            tries++;
```

Comment: also uses a 0-based index, while incrementing after the break. move tries++ to the first line of the do, and you'll have it.